# Drop elements of a list stored in a pandas column based on a character

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

```
index
[c.7C>G, (p.Pro3Ala), c.19G>T, (p.Gly7Cys),   ...]
[c.49C>T, (p.Gln17Ter), c.79A>T, (p.Thr27Ser),...]
[c.37A>C, (p.Thr13Pro), c.70A>T, (p.Ile24Phe),...]
[c.17C>A, (p.Ala6Asp), c.19G>T, (p.Gly7Cys),  ...]
[c.19G>A, (p.Gly7Ser), c.27A>T, (p.Glu9Asp),  ...]
```

I have a column in a dataframe which contains lists of strings like the one above. I am trying to remove every entry that begins with `c.`. I am able to work out how to do this on single lists, but I'm struggling to apply that same logic to lists stored in a dataframe.

Comment: `df[col].apply(lambda lst: [val for val in lst if not val.startswith('c.')])`

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much!!
Do you have an easy to understand resource on how lambda works? Its always very useful, but I haven't really understood a lot of the guides...

Comment: lambdas are just functions, defined in place. it is the same as defining a function `def filter_c(lst): return [...]`, then calling `df[col].apply(filter_c)`

Comment: @Marat, please post an answer. It's important for all other users with a similar problem.

Comment: @Corralien done. I assumed it's too trivial for an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to apply the single list approach to every cell:

```
df[col].apply(lambda lst: [val for val in lst if not val.startswith('c.')])
```

A more verbose version would be:

```
def filter_prefix(lst, prefix='c.'):
    """ filter out strings starting with `prefix` out of a list"""
    return [val for val in lst if not val.startswith(prefix)]

df[col] = df[col].apply(filter_prefix)
```